# Chrome extension ExecuteScript not firing XRM JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, google-chrome-extension

Dynamics CRM has its own XRM JS APIs, Which I'm trying to execute in a chrome extension that I'm working on. I'm using the below code.

```js
chrome.tabs.query({ currentWindow: true, active: true }, function(tabs) {
  chrome.scripting.executeScript({
    target: { tabId: tabs[0].id },
    func: () => {
      Xrm.Utility.alertDialog("Hello world", () => { });
    }
  });
});
```

```js
Xrm.Utility.alertDialog("Hello world", () => { });
```

This code just shows a message box on the Dynamics CRM screen using this Dynamics API method.

If I run this code in the chrome console, it shows the message properly. If I just put `alert("Hello world")"`, that code also runs which confirms that `executeScript` is working fine, but somehow `Xrm` isn't available.

Manifest.json
[image]

Answer (score 1):

After overflowing the stack a few times, I learned that the script injection needs to happen by explicitly creating a script tag and injecting it on the page body. similar to the code below.

```
function runOnXrmPage() {

    // create a script tag
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.src = chrome.runtime.getURL('webscript.js');
    s.onload = function () {
        this.remove();
    };
    (document.head || document.documentElement).appendChild(s);

}

chrome.tabs.query({ currentWindow: true, active: true }, function (tabs) {
            chrome.scripting.executeScript({
                target: { tabId: tabs[0].id },
                func: () => {
                    runOnXrmPage();
                }
            });
});
```

All the Xrm code was placed in `webscript.js` file and manifest was updated as pasted below.

```
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    {
      "resources": [ "webscript.js" ],
      "matches": [ "https://*.crm.dynamics.com/*" ]
    }
  ]
```